# Lets Encrypt Certificate Expired On One Server With Load Balancer

Tags: digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, traefik

I am relatively new to the Traefik / Digital Ocean setup I am working with so not sure what is going on but I have seen that when viewing my sites it sometimes shows that the SSL cert expired.  Sure enough, we are using a Load Balancer on Digital Ocean with 2 servers.  I'm assuming that one of the servers did not renew Let's Encrypt Cert but not sure what to do to fix this.  I don't see any cronjob setup to update these certs.  Could it be handled on Digital Ocean's side?

I see the following settings in traefik.toml for both the servers using the load balancers:

```
# Acme setting are used for letsencrypt to get the wildcard cert.
[acme]
email = "admin@mysite.com"
storage = "traefik/acme/account"
caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
entryPoint = "https"
[acme.dnsChallenge]
provider = "digitalocean" # DNS Provider name (cloudflare, OVH, gandi...)
delayBeforeCheck = 0
[[acme.domains]]
main = "*.mystagingsite.com"
```

Comment: It is unusual to get two certs issued for the same set of domains for the same period. Instead put the certs in front of a load balancer and use the same cert for everything behind it.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I believe I have setup now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the certificate did not create it will try to recreate it on a daily basis.  Also, if you reset the server it will recreate it on start.